Deploying express,node,mongodb stack web app into Azure error
Can I know what should i add in order to deploy my web apps into the azure.It seem like it cannot display ejs file. I able to run the web app in local but once is deploy the azure failed to display anything and receive a 504 gateway timeout.
https://github.com/codecinn27/flood_observatory_idp/blob/main/app.js this is my github repo.
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const app = express()
const port = 3000;
const url = process.env.MONGO_URL;
const clientOptions = { serverApi: { version: '1', strict: true, deprecationErrors:true } };
const dbName = 'Idp_Project';
const Data = require('./models/data');

app.use(express.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));


async function main() {
     try{
    await mongoose.connect(url, clientOptions);
    await mongoose.connection.db.admin().command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
}catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
}
 } 

main().catch(console.error);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home');
})

app.get('/input',(req,res)=>{
   res.render('input');
 })

app.post('/input', async (req,res)=>{
   try {
    const data = new Data(req.body.data);
    // console.log(data);
    await data.save();
    console.log("Data saved:", data);
    res.status(201).redirect(`/`);
 } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error saving data:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
//res.send(req.body);
})


app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
 })[![enter image description here][1]][1]




I added the following line to your app.js file:
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

This line assigns the port number from the environment variable PORT if it is set, otherwise it defaults to 3000. This allows flexibility in port configuration when deploying the application across different environments.
When deploying your application to various environments (such as development, testing, or production), you might want to run it on different ports. By using process.env.PORT, you can easily configure the port through environment variables without modifying your code.
app.js:
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const url = process.env.MONGO_URL;
const clientOptions = { serverApi: { version: '1', strict: true, deprecationErrors: true } };
const dbName = 'Idp_Project';
const Data = require('./models/data');

app.use(express.json());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
async function main() {
    try{
        await mongoose.connect(url);
        console.log("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!");
    }catch (error) {
        console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
    }
}
main().catch(console.error);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home');
})
app.get('/input',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('input');
})
app.post('/input', async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const data = new Data(req.body.data);
        await data.save();
        console.log("Data saved:", data);
        res.status(201).redirect(`/`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error saving data:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
  })


package.json:
{
    "name": "website_4",
  "description": "  #\u0000 \u0000f\u0000l\u0000o\u0000o\u0000d\u0000_\u0000o\u0000b\u0000s\u0000e\u0000r\u0000v\u0000a\u0000t\u0000o\u0000r\u0000y\u0000_\u0000i\u0000d\u0000p\u0000\r\u0000 \u0000",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.10",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}

Azure App Service Output:


